# how to divide a row with the previous one and that the values remain in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, finance

My problem is that I have time series, and I need to create a new column that gives me the natural logarithm of today's price divided by yesterday's price, and that these values are in a new column

```py
#Accion1['Rentabilidad1'] = Accion1.apply(lambda row: np.log(Promedio), axis=1)
Accion1['Rentabilidad'] = np.log(Accion1['Promedio'])
Accion1
```

[image]

I was thinking of creating new variables and splitting iloc[0]/iloc[1] but it doesn't work either, please help ‍

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would grab all of the previous dates and save them to a separate list:

```
fechas_anteriores = [x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") for x in Accion1["Fecha anterior"]]
```

Then I would create a new column called `Promedio anterior` using .loc, making reference to `fechas_anteriores`:

```
Accion1["Promedio anterior"] = [fecha[0] if len(fecha) > 0 else None \
                                for fecha in [Accion1.loc[Accion1["Fecha de cotizacion"] == dt.strptime(fecha_anterior, "%d-%m-%Y")]["Promedio"].to_list() \
                                for fecha_anterior in fechas_anteriores]]
```

Finally I would execute the division:

```
Accion1["Division"] = Accion1["Rentabilidad"]/Accion1["Promedio anterior"]
```

You could do all of this in one line of course, though it would be less readable.